# Find weekdays in a date range

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to push dates within a range in an array, but it's pushing only the last date n times instead of required individual dates.

```
function getBusinessDatesCount(startDatetest, endDatetest) {
    var curDate = startDatetest;
    var weekdays = [];
    while (curDate <= endDatetest) {
        var dayOfWeek = curDate.getDay();
        if (!((dayOfWeek === 6) || (dayOfWeek === 0))) {
            weekdays.push(curDate);
        }
        curDate.setDate(curDate.getDate() + 1);
    }
    console.log(weekdays);
}
var startDatetest = new Date('05/03/2016');
var endDatetest = new Date('05/10/2016');
var numOfDates = getBusinessDatesCount(startDatetest, endDatetest);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have two `date` objects in memory currently, the `startDatetest` and the  `endDatetest` - changing `curDate` will change `startDatetest`, because object variables essentially reference *memory locations* in Javascript. (Creating a new variable that references the object, such as `curDate = startDatetest`, does not clone the object, it only copies the reference to the object's location in memory). You need to *clone* the `date` object instead:

```js
function getBusinessDatesCount(startDatetest, endDatetest) {
  var curDate = startDatetest;
  var weekdays = [];
  while (curDate <= endDatetest) {
    var dayOfWeek = curDate.getDay();
    if (!((dayOfWeek === 6) || (dayOfWeek === 0))) {
      weekdays.push(new Date(curDate.getTime()));
    }
    curDate.setDate(curDate.getDate() + 1);
  }
  console.log(weekdays);
}
var startDatetest = new Date('05/03/2016');
var endDatetest = new Date('05/10/2016');
var numOfDates = getBusinessDatesCount(startDatetest, endDatetest);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to push a **new date object** into the array. Otherwise, you will add references to the same object over and over again.

```
function getBusinessDatesCount(startDatetest, endDatetest) {
    var curDate = startDatetest;
    var weekdays = [];
    while (curDate <= endDatetest) {
        var dayOfWeek = curDate.getDay();
        if(!((dayOfWeek === 6) || (dayOfWeek === 0))) {
           weekdays.push(new Date(curDate));
        }   
        curDate.setDate(curDate.getDate() + 1);
    }
    console.log(weekdays);
}
var startDatetest = new Date('05/03/2016');
var endDatetest = new Date('05/10/2016');
var numOfDates = getBusinessDatesCount(startDatetest,endDatetest);
```